# SetCurSel in CDateTimeCtrl

Tags: mfc, datepicker

Can somebody please tell me how to set the cursor position in an MFC CDateTimeCtrl?

After somebody enters a date and presses an "Add" button, I clear my date control contents with m_Date.SetWindowText( "" ); The problem I have is that when tabbing back onto the control, it still shows the year as being highlighted. My date control is of the format DD/MM/YYYY

All I want to to is make the selected text the date (DD) rather than the last field (YYYY) selected.

Ideally, I would like to be able to get a CEdit* pointer to the control's textbox. That way I could use CEdit::SetCurSel() and everything would be fine.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its safe to say it can't be done. I ended up writing my own control to do the job as have other people as well.